# Как выбрать 1 базовую станцию для модема

Tags: модемы

У меня есть модем Билайн, он вставлен в маршрутизатор Keenetic Omni , мой модем постоянно переключается между вышками(Станциями), как привязать его лишь к одной станции ?

Comment: Направленную антенну использовать!? :)

Comment: @Visman нужно именно программное решение